# Bootstrap 4 Footer height is way too big, but there's whitespace if fixed height is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a basic layout with some HTML code. I'm using Bootstrap 4. The length of the footer is REALLY big. I don't know how to make it smaller.

Here is the page:

http://wsbstutoring.com/revamp/

I don't need that much of a footer. But when I put a fixed height on it, there's a bunch of whitespace left underneath? I put my code through W3C Validator and it's validating fine with no errors. I also changed 'col-lg-4'(*3) to 'col-md-4'(*3). Should it be smaller? Does that make a difference?

```
<!-- Begin 3 Column Footer -->
<footer class="footer"> 
<br>  
<div class="container"> 
  <div class="row padding-20">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="img/logo-white.png" class="img-fluid img-logo-footer" alt="Work Smart, Be Smart Tutoring" title="Work Smart, Be Smart Tutoring">
        <p class="footer-text">P.O. Box 928 <br>
         Groveland, FL, 34736</p>
        <h3 class="footer-h3 padding-left-75">352-577-9235</h3>
        <a href="https://facebook.com/worksmartbesmarttutoring" class="social-media padding-left-75" target="_blank"><i class="fab social-media fa-facebook-square"></i></a> &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <a href="/contact.html"><i class="fas fa-envelope social-media"></i></a>


      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="footer-text padding-20">
          <h3 class="footer-h3 padding-left-75">Useful Links</h3>
          <ul class="list-unstyled padding-left-75 line-height-36">
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/subjects.html">Subjects</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about/financing.html">Financing Options</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pricing">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a href="/test-prep">Test Prep</a></li>
            <li><a href="/forms">Forms</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="footer-text padding-20">
            <h3 class="footer-h3">Latest Blog Posts</h3>
            <br>
            <img src="img/blog/lightbulb.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Sample Blog Post">
            <p class="text-center"><a href="#"><strong>5 Tips to ease the transition from Public School to Homeschooling</strong></a></p>


            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
  </footer>

 <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
 <script src="jquery/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
 <script src="bootstrap/js/main.js"></script>

 </body>

 </html>
```

I expected for the footer to be similar to the one here on Stack Overflow's website, a decent size, not what I have now. Too big. Thanks in advance for your answers!

EDIT: I'm adding a photo of what it's doing now. (You should be able to view it on my website but just in case you can't.)

[image: Click to view image]

Comment: No, the col stuff doesn't make a difference, that handles width, not the height of the footer, which is what I assume is the problem? It probably has something to do with the padding-20 on the row. If you want the horizontal padding, but not vertical padding, you need to specify that. Also, why is there a linebreak (<br>) between the footer tag and the container?

Comment: @Alex oh, I didn't realize that. Well, if that's not what's causing the problem, I'm not sure what is. And yes, the height of the footer is the problem.

Comment: @alex I just took off the padding-20, and it did nothing. and there's a <br> tag because I needed to quickly put space between the two for breathing room. I know this would be better done via CSS like margin. I will fix it. Do you have any other suggestions as to what could be causing it?

Comment: The problem seems to be the column on the left, but I'm not sure why. Give the footer a fixed height (height: 400px), and add the h-100 class to the container, the row, and the columns. I have no idea why this works, but it does. Also, remove the <br> tag, and give the row some top padding instead if you need it. I'm not going to put this as an answer, because I don't know the cause :P

Comment: it KINDA worked, thanks. Do you know why my logo image is all stretched out now? what's the fix for that?

Comment: It's not for me, did you remove the <br>, and give the footer a fixed height?

Comment: @Alex I just removed the <br> and added a margin top. there's a fixed height as well. Hard to do a hard refresh to see the update. The logo is fine now. there's only a little bit of whitespace at the bottom now, not as much as before.

Comment: You need padding-top, not margin-top, and the <br> is still there.